# entity framework retrieve data as list(of string)

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following code to select all counties given a stateid from a counties table.

```
 Public Shared Function GetCountiesfromState(statename As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim context As New Model.teckEntities()
    Dim query = From c In context.counties Where c.stateId = 7 Select c
    Return query.ToList()
End Function
```

I get any error that query is returning a list of model. any thoughts on where the error lies?

Comment: How do you plan to "convert" a country to a string? You need to select one of its string properties: `Where c.stateId = 7 Select c.Name` etc. Or return the whole country list `GetCountiesfromState(statename As String) As List(Of Country)`

Comment: Good point. I changed the return to list(of county) but my drop down im binding to has nothing in it. I set the list as the dataource and databind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a `Name` (or `Title`) field on the County entity, it should be as simple as:

```
Public Shared Function GetCountiesfromState(statename As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim context As New Model.teckEntities()
    ' Here is the difference:
    Dim query = From c In context.counties Where c.stateId = 7 Select c.Name
    Return query.ToList()
End Function
```

In your code above you were selecting the `c` which, is a County entity, not necessarily a string property.  By selecting `c.Name` (or `c.Title`) instead, you'll be building a list of strings instead of a list of county entities.

Cheers.